# Car Making Noise After It speeds up

Tags: noise

Car(2008 Volkswagen Jetta) makes high pitched noise like a cricket after I accelerate(to about 35 mph or 3rd gear) independent of braking. The noise continues even if I come to a full stop but the engine is still running. The weird part is it doesn't always make this noise, so I'm not sure if the mechanic will catch it.

Also the noise seems to change according to the heater fan level. The noise mostly goes away if I turn off the fan. However, given that it is 13F outside, I couldn't go too long without the fan being on, so I couldn't collect enough data.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_cTBf1FLL8

Comment: It would be good to mention your vehicle's make, model and year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to hear the noise in the video. The observation that it changes with fan speed is a strong indication that it has something to do with the blower fan.

It is not uncommon for broken fan blades to cause rotary imbalance, resulting in the fan sounding very noisy when in operation.

Note that this explanation would not explain any noises you might be hearing while the fan is off. If this is the case, you need to describe the circumstances in more detail.